# Run android_apps with errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ubuntu-12.04, ros

I follow this tutorial to [download android_apps](http://wiki.epfl.ch/roscontrol/androidstudio-and-rosjava), I have Android SDK revision 24.0.2, Android Studio 1.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.
I catkin_make the workspace successfully, then I source the setup.bash file, after that I start the Android studio from the Terminal with studio.sh, then I import the android_apps files to android studio and build the project successfully.

When I tried to run one of the apps (e.g. teleop, map_nav, make_map...etc) I have the following errors:

**First one:**

Error:Execution failed for task ':teleop:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /home/dell/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /home/dell/android/src/android_apps/teleop/build/intermediates/dex/debug /home/dell/android/src/android_apps/teleop/build/intermediates/classes/debug /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ros.rosjava_messages/rosgraph_msgs/1.9.50/5bda692b5f32449d109eb8ac74cc77a23ff78dc7/rosgraph_msgs-1.9.50.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/actionlib_msgs/1.10.6/actionlib_msgs-1.10.6.jar /home/dell/android/src/android_apps/teleop/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.github.rosjava.android_extras/gingerbread/0.1.4/classes.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/diagnostic_msgs/1.10.6/diagnostic_msgs-1.10.6.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/rosjava_test_msgs/0.1.27/rosjava_test_msgs-0.1.27.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf2_msgs/0.4.12/tf2_msgs-0.4.12.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/nav_msgs/1.10.6/nav_msgs-1.10.6.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/geometry_msgs/1.10.6/geometry_msgs-1.10.6.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/std_msgs/0.5.8/std_msgs-0.5.8.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava_geometry/0.1.6/rosjava_geometry-0.1.6.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ros.rosjava_messages/gateway_msgs/0.6.5/c6d16dc005d08f0bc90f058fded32b5342df6be2/gateway_msgs-0.6.5.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ros.rosjava_messages/rocon_app_manager_msgs/0.6.5/c85330ffce2bef71ef78ee31d30a9de3f79ccc75/rocon_app_manager_msgs-0.6.5.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/sensor_msgs/1.10.6/sensor_msgs-1.10.6.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/40719ea6961c0cb6afaeb6a921eaa1f6afd4cfdf/jsr305-1.3.9.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.ws.commons/ws-commons-util/1.0.1/126e80ff798fece634bc94e61f8be8a8da00be60/ws-commons-util-1.0.1.jar /home/dell/android/src/android_apps/teleop/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.ros.android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/0.1.3/classes.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec/1.3.0/f8690570eb0913d750262bb4223eed30b0d619ed/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec-1.3.0.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_core/apache_xmlrpc_server/0.1.6/apache_xmlrpc_server-0.1.6.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_core/apache_xmlrpc_client/0.1.6/apache_xmlrpc_client-0.1.6.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging/1.1.1/7657caf2c78e1d79c74d36f2ae128a115f7cc180/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar /home/dell/android/src/android_apps/teleop/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.github.rosjava.android_apps/application_management/0.1.4/classes.jar /home/dell/android/src/android_apps/teleop/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.ros.android_core/android_honeycomb_mr2/0.1.3/classes.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_bootstrap/gradle_plugins/0.1.22/gradle_plugins-0.1.22.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_core/apache_xmlrpc_common/0.1.6/apache_xmlrpc_common-0.1.6.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6/4572d589699f09d866a226a14b7f4323c6d8f040/commons-pool-1.6.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_bootstrap/message_generation/0.1.22/message_generation-0.1.22.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/3.8.2/7e4cde26b53a9a0e3fe5b00d1dbbc7cc1d46060/junit-3.8.2.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/b1b6ea3b7e4aa4f492509a4952029cd8e48019ad/commons-io-2.4.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.net/2.0.0/3e78766072ff5a5cf3f5431d973c430c94ec612/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.net-2.0.0.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.8/af3be3f74d25fc5163b54f56a0d394b462dafafd/commons-codec-1.8.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/ce1edb914c94ebc388f086c6827e8bdeec71ac2/commons-lang-2.6.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient/3.1.0/c493a925a091ac3d8f449d9265fe12482dabb2a7/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.jar /home/dell/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava/0.1.6/rosjava-0.1.6.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/dnsjava/dnsjava/2.1.1/5708df81cf6dbff545695f0be6380b7bbc85accc/dnsjava-2.1.1.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty/3.5.2.Final/e6fb74a0699abe108969b2ec1f269391169a0426/netty-3.5.2.Final.jar /home/dell/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/12.0/5bc66dd95b79db1e437eb08adba124a3e4088dc0/guava-12.0.jar

**Second error:**

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;
        at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
        at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:685)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

Did any one faced these errors before? or do you have any idea how to solve them?

Thanks